# How to recompile Delphi component containing asm in 64bit?

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to recompile the (old) TProfDHTMLEdit unit in 64bit environment with Delphi XE5. The component is old and dismissed but I need it because I could not found anything similar to easily substitute it for my purpose.

I'm having trouble with three internal routines that are hard coded directly in asm. I'm not capable to convert them in pure Pascal. Anyone has already solved a similar problem?

The parts to convert are:

```
procedure TProfOleControl.GetEventMethod(DispID: TDispID; var Method: TMethod);
asm
{$IFDEF WIN32}
        PUSH    EBX
        PUSH    ESI
        PUSH    EDI
        PUSH    ECX
        MOV     EBX,EAX
        MOV     ECX,[EBX].TProfOleControl.FControlData
        MOV     EDI,[ECX].TControlData2.EventCount
        MOV     ESI,[ECX].TControlData2.EventDispIDs
        XOR     EAX,EAX
        JMP     @@1
@@0:    CMP     EDX,[ESI].Integer[EAX*4]
        JE      @@2
        INC     EAX
@@1:    CMP     EAX,EDI
        JNE     @@0
        XOR     EAX,EAX
        XOR     EDX,EDX
        JMP     @@3
@@2:    PUSH    EAX
        CMP     [ECX].TControlData2.Version, 401
        JB      @@2a
        MOV     EAX, [ECX].TControlData2.FirstEventOfs
        TEST    EAX, EAX
        JNE     @@2b
@@2a:   MOV     EAX, [EBX]
        CALL    TObject.ClassParent
        CALL    TObject.InstanceSize
        ADD     EAX, 7
        AND     EAX, not 7
@@2b:   ADD     EBX, EAX
        POP     EAX
        MOV     EDX,[EBX][EAX*8].TMethod.Data
        MOV     EAX,[EBX][EAX*8].TMethod.Code
@@3:    POP     ECX
        MOV     [ECX].TMethod.Code,EAX
        MOV     [ECX].TMethod.Data,EDX
        POP     EDI
        POP     ESI
        POP     EBX
{$ENDIF}
end;
```

or

```
procedure TProfOleControl.InvokeEvent(DispID: TDispID; var Params: TDispParams);
var
  EventMethod: TMethod;
begin
  GetEventMethod(DispID, EventMethod);
  if Integer(EventMethod.Code) < $10000 then Exit;
  try
{$IFDEF WIN32}
    asm
              PUSH    EBX
              PUSH    ESI
              MOV     ESI, Params
              MOV     EBX, [ESI].TDispParams.cArgs
              TEST    EBX, EBX
              JZ      @@7
              MOV     ESI, [ESI].TDispParams.rgvarg
              MOV     EAX, EBX
              SHL     EAX, 4
              XOR     EDX, EDX
              ADD     ESI, EAX
      @@1:    SUB     ESI, 16
              MOV     EAX, dword ptr [ESI]
              CMP     AX, varSingle
              JA      @@3
              JE      @@5
      @@2:    TEST    DL,DL
              JNE     @@2a
              MOV     ECX, ESI
              INC     DL
              TEST    EAX, varArray
              JNZ     @@6
              MOV     ECX, dword ptr [ESI+8]
              JMP     @@6
      @@2a:   TEST    EAX, varArray
              JZ      @@5
              PUSH    ESI
              JMP     @@6
      @@3:    CMP     AX, varDate
              JA      @@2
      @@4:    PUSH    dword ptr [ESI+12]
      @@5:    PUSH    dword ptr [ESI+8]
      @@6:    DEC     EBX
              JNE     @@1
      @@7:    MOV     EDX, Self
              MOV     EAX, EventMethod.Data
              CALL    EventMethod.Code
              POP     ESI
              POP     EBX
    end
{$ENDIF}
  except
    Application.HandleException(Self)
  end
end;
```

Comment: It might help if you show (one of) the asm parts. The issue is probably specific assembler statements. Googling 'delphi 64 bit assembler' can also help.

Comment: I applaud your initial instinct to convert these routines to pure pascal. But we can't help without seeing the functions.

Comment: Sorry, I added the asm code in the original post!

Comment: That's not too hard to convert, but it will take a fair amount of time. It would be a lot easier for someone familiar with `TProfOleControl`. That's not me.  I'm not sure I can bring myself to do it for you. Sorry. Whoever wrote that code should be publicly flayed every day at dawn for a week.

Comment: These seem to be slightly adjusted versions of the methods of `TOleControl` with the same name. `TOleControl` is one of the VCL's own types, you can check the XE5 implementation (which quite possibly does use pure Pascal) to get something that already mostly works.

Comment: hwd thanks for the advise, I'm looking into Vcl.OleCtrls.pas to see how they solved the question.

Comment: The asm code is identical to the x86 code in the OleCtrls. So either copy the purepascal/x64 code to the TProfOleControl or another solution: inherit TProfOleControl from TOleControl and remove these methods from TProfOleControl so it uses those from TOleControl.

Comment: Thx to all, using the pieces of code of TOleControl I solved the problem. Now the component seems working in 64bit environment!

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be slightly adjusted versions of the methods of TOleControl with the same name. TOleControl is one of the VCL's own types, you can check the XE5 implementation (which quite possibly does use pure Pascal) to get something that already mostly works.